# How to scroll down automatically inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row wrapper">
        <div class="col-8 left-side">
            @if(count($dreams) > 0)
                @foreach($dreams as $dream)
                    <p class="dream-body">{{$dream->dream}}</p>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 right-side">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <span></span>
                <a href="/about" class="about-button">?</a>
                <a href="/upload" class="add-button">+</a>
            </div>
            <p class="blue-text float-right position-absolute rotate position-vertical-text">asd</p>
            <p class="position-absolute position-percentage blue-text">23%</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The site stand from to sides, left and right. The right side is static, not moving at all. But in the left side, I'm inserting a lot of text. The left side should move up by itself, without the user scrolling, so the user van read the texts there.

I have the following javascript to achieve this:

```
function startScrollDown() {

    let leftSide = $('.left-side');

    leftSide.stop().animate({
        scrollTop: leftSide[0].scrollHeight
    }, 100000);
}
```

The problem with this, is that it start slow, but after the `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight` values change, and according to scroll distance, the scrolling becomes faster and faster, after a point it's just super fast.

How should I modify this, to achieve a same speed scrolling?

Comment: Did you try providing `easing: linear` as an argument to the animate function?
`leftSide.stop().animate({...props}, 100000, 'linear');`

Comment: @IshantSolanki thank you, saved my night!

Comment: @QuentinVeron as per the docs, default is set to `swing`

Comment: @IshantSolanki I was referring to the [native method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate), mb.

Comment: @QuentinVeron. I see. You stand correct. However, the problem states the use of jQuery, so i was referring to [this](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add linear to the arguments for a linear animation.

```
function startScrollDown() {

  let leftSide = $('.left-side');

  leftSide.stop().animate({
      scrollTop: leftSide[0].scrollHeight
  }, 100000, 'linear');
}
```